# Delete rows based on values in the columns and a thresh hold value

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a table, the start is below:

```
                       SM_H1455     SM_H1456  SM_H1457   SM_H1461     SM_H1462     SM_H1463 
ENSG00000001617.7         0            0          0           0          0           0                              
ENSG00000001626.9         0            0          0           0          0           0                                                            
ENSG00000002587.5         10           0          6           2          0           2                                               
ENSG00000002726.15        8            14         0           2          16          2                                                                
ENSG00000002745.8         6            2          2           0          0           4
```

I want to delete rows in which >= 80% of columns have the value 0. So I have 6 cols here, if 5  or more of the columns in a row have a 0, then that row needs to be deleted.

I currently have this code:

```
data = data[!rowSums(data == 0), ]
```

But this code delete all the rows as long as they have a 0, without taking into account the 80% thresh hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that @Hong Ooi's answer is incorrect in this case.  This will give you the result that you have asked for:

```
data <- data[rowSums(data==0)/ncol(data) < 0.8, ]
```

`data==0` returns a data frame filled with `TRUE` if the value at that location is equal zero, otherwise `FALSE`.  Numerically, R treats `TRUE`as having a value of 1 and `FALSE` as having a value of zero.

`rowSums` adds up the numerical equivalents of the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values for each row in the data frame returned from `data==0`.  `rowSums(data==0)` basically gives the number of elements in each row in `data` which are zero.

`ncol` is the number of columns in the original data object.

`rowSums(data==0)/ncol(data)` is therefore the proportion of elements equal to zero in each row.

Finally, we can discard the rows where the above proprtion are not less than 80% by filtering (using [] notation).

UPDATE: @Hong Ooi's edit means that their answer is also correct now.

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
data <- data[rowSums(data != 0)/ncol(data) > 0.2, ]
```

Comment: Hi, sry to be a pain, but would you mind explaining your code? What does dividing `rowSums` by `ncol` do?

Comment: Oops, left out the `!= 0` in the row sums. It's as @Cnrl explained. Dropping rows with 80% or more zeros is the same as keeping rows with 20% or more nonzeros.